# How would you explain stochastic discrimination?

Tags: machine-learning

...to a layman?

So, what is SD?
Taken from the abstract of [this article](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.16.5451&rep=rep1&type=pdf):

*Abstract. The method of stochastic discrimination (SD) introduced by Klein- berg ([6], [7]) is a new method in pattern recognition. It works by producing weak classifiers and then combining them via the Central Limit Theorem to form a strong classifier. SD is overtraining-resistant, has a high convergence rate, and can work quite well in practice. **However, some strict assumptions involved in SD and the difficulties in understanding SD have limited its practical use**. ...*

Comment: Wherever Stochastic discrimination exists, fight for the rights of those who speak the Stochastic language!  (Sorry, it's Friday evening here...)

Comment: :) 
Well... first time for everything, also a downvote

Comment: Sorry about that: I'll compensate (+1).  It might be nice to provide a reference to, or say a brief word, about what stochastic discrimination is.  That could stave off the downvotes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, whuber :) sloppy initial work tho, I deserved it

Comment: That's a great improvement, thank you.  I look forward to seeing good replies!

Comment: Thank *you*. All these machine learning techniques. All these machine learning names. *No, we are not gonna call it variables, we're gonna call it features*. Back to school for me :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what constitutes layman's terms, but SD is a classifier. Given a training set which consists of vectors of numbers and a classification, it learns to recognize patterns in the vectors and then can classify new vectors that it has never seen before. For example, if you give it a bunch of skull measurement data that look like this:

[ 45, 23, 66, 3, 17 ] -> male
[ 52, 12, 56, 4, 10 ] -> female
[ 43, 18, 70, 5, 11 ] -> male

And then you give it a new vector of measurements that looks like this:

[ 50, 12, 60, 4, 11 ]

SD will tell you if it thinks those new measurements belong to a male skull or a female skull. Of course, you need a lot more training data than just three vectors. But that's generally how it works. You can classify anything with SD: hand-written digits, weather forecasts, whatever. As long as you can specify the data in terms of a vector and classification, you're good to go.

Neural networks do the same general thing and are much more famous than SD. SD has advantages over neural nets, though. It tends to be a bit more accurate and also is "over-training resistant". If neural networks train on their data for too long, they can learn to be too specific in their classification. SD does not have this weakness. SD is also based on a much more solid mathematical foundation than neural nets.

Hope this helps.